# Adding "Attention" line to scrlttr2

Tags: koma-script, scrlttr2

In business letters, there is a convention of having a line which saying "Attention: so and so persons" before the start of the main letter.

I'm wondering what my options are wrt doing this in the KOMA `scrlttr2` class. The following attempt uses the so-called "reference line". Is that my only option?

In a related question, in this particular example, adding a custom variable to the reference line adds Date: above the date of the letter. How can I remove that?

```
\documentclass[12pt,sections,headheight=30pt,headinclude,firstfoot=false,enlargefirstpage=true,foldmarks=false,foldmarks=blmtP,fromalign=center,fromphone,fromemail,version=last, backaddress=false, subject=titled]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{scrpage2}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fouriernc}

\begin{document}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Name}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Address}
\renewcommand{\phonename}{Landline}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{Landline phone number}
\renewcommand{\mobilephonename}{Mobile}
\setkomavar{frommobilephone}{Mobile phone numbers}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{Email address}
\setkomavar{signature}{(\usekomavar{fromname})}
\newkomavar*[ATTN:]{attention}
\setkomavar{attention}{Recipient 1, Recipient 2\\ and Recipient 3}
\setkomavar{subject}{Subject}
\setkomavar{date}{\today}

\setkomavar{firsthead}{%
  \parbox{\linewidth}{\centering
    {\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont
    \hspace{\textwidth}
    \usekomavar{fromname}\\
    \usekomavar{fromaddress}\\
    \usekomavar*{phoneseparator}\usekomavar{phoneseparator}\usekomavar{fromphone}\\
    \usekomavar*{mobilephoneseparator}\usekomavar{mobilephoneseparator}\usekomavar{frommobilephone}\\
    \usekomavar*{emailseparator}\usekomavar{emailseparator}\usekomavar{fromemail}
    }
  }%
}

\def\today{29th April, 2018}
\begin{letter}{To Address}

  \opening{Addressee}

\closing{Yours Sincerely,}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine the description of variable `date` to remove »Date« above the date in the reference line:

```
\setkomavar*{date}{}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,
%sections,% unused global option (unknown to scrlttr2}
headheight=30pt,headinclude,firstfoot=false,enlargefirstpage=true,
foldmarks=false,
%foldmarks=blmtP,% unused if foldmarks=false
fromalign=center,fromphone,fromemail,version=last, backaddress=false, subject=titled]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% scrpage2 is outdated

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fouriernc}

\begin{document}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Name}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Address}
\renewcommand{\phonename}{Landline}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{Landline phone number}
\renewcommand{\mobilephonename}{Mobile}
\setkomavar{frommobilephone}{Mobile phone numbers}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{Email address}
\setkomavar{signature}{(\usekomavar{fromname})}
\newkomavar*[ATTN:]{attention}
\setkomavar{attention}{Recipient 1, Recipient 2\\ and Recipient 3}
\setkomavar{subject}{Subject}
\setkomavar{date}{29th April, 2018}% avoids redefining \today
\setkomavar*{date}{}% remove "Date" above the date in the reference line

\setkomavar{firsthead}{%
  \parbox{\linewidth}{\centering
    {\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont
    \hspace{\textwidth}
    \usekomavar{fromname}\\
    \usekomavar{fromaddress}\\
    \usekomavar*{phoneseparator}\usekomavar{phoneseparator}\usekomavar{fromphone}\\
    \usekomavar*{mobilephoneseparator}\usekomavar{mobilephoneseparator}\usekomavar{frommobilephone}\\
    \usekomavar*{emailseparator}\usekomavar{emailseparator}\usekomavar{fromemail}
    }
  }%
}

\begin{letter}{To Address}
\opening{Addressee}
\closing{Yours Sincerely,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

---

You can also use `location`:

```
\setkomavar{location}{%
  \usekomavar*{attention}\\
  \usekomavar{attention}
}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,
%sections,% unused global option (unknown to scrlttr2}
headheight=30pt,headinclude,firstfoot=false,enlargefirstpage=true,
foldmarks=false,
%foldmarks=blmtP,% unused if foldmarks=false
fromalign=center,fromphone,fromemail,version=last, backaddress=false, subject=titled]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% scrpage2 is outdated

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fouriernc}

\begin{document}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Name}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Address}
\renewcommand{\phonename}{Landline}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{Landline phone number}
\renewcommand{\mobilephonename}{Mobile}
\setkomavar{frommobilephone}{Mobile phone numbers}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{Email address}
\setkomavar{signature}{(\usekomavar{fromname})}
\newkomavar[ATTN:]{attention}% <- changed
\setkomavar{attention}{Recipient 1, Recipient 2 and Recipient 3}% <- changed
\setkomavar{subject}{Subject}
\setkomavar{date}{29th April, 2018}% avoids redefining \today

\setkomavar{location}{%
  \usekomavar*{attention}\\
  \usekomavar{attention}
}

\setkomavar{firsthead}{%
  \parbox{\linewidth}{\centering
    {\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont
    \hspace{\textwidth}
    \usekomavar{fromname}\\
    \usekomavar{fromaddress}\\
    \usekomavar*{phoneseparator}\usekomavar{phoneseparator}\usekomavar{fromphone}\\
    \usekomavar*{mobilephoneseparator}\usekomavar{mobilephoneseparator}\usekomavar{frommobilephone}\\
    \usekomavar*{emailseparator}\usekomavar{emailseparator}\usekomavar{fromemail}
    }
  }%
}

\begin{letter}{To Address}
\opening{Addressee}
\closing{Yours Sincerely,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions. Of these two options for the Attn line, which do you think is the better option?

Comment: Also, why is the "ATTN" so small, and what is the best way to enlarge it? Should I simply wrap it in \large or something? (Though \large is too large.)

Comment: Normally there are more informations in the reference line, eg. "Your reference", "Your letter from" etc. The reference description only gives a hint which information is provided. To  get the same font as for the reference change font element `refname`: `\setkomafont{refname}{}` or `\setkomafont{refname}{\usekomafont{refvalue}}`. But then I would prefer the second suggestion using `location`

Comment: Thank you for the hint about the font. But I'm not sure what you mean by "But then I would prefer the second suggestion using location". Are you saying you prefer the second method?

Comment: Yes, especially if there would be no more information in the reference line and "ATTN" should have the same font size and the description "Date"  should be removed.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Directly above the subject seems like a more natural place for this, though.

Comment: It is your decision (and it is opinion based) ;-)